# How to find files, parse and modify the results, and sort from the command line?

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, awk

Here is an example of what I'm currently doing in a bash terminal on a linux machine:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.jar" -print0 |xargs -0 md5sum |awk '{print $1,$2}'
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a  ./lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a  ./libsrc/jlgui3.0/lib/jorbis.jar
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a  ./libsrc/VorbisSPI1.0.3/lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a  ./lib/zip/jlgui3.0/lib/jorbis.jar
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a  ./lib/zip/VorbisSPI1.0.2/lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar
```

I would like to modify the command so the resulting output would be:

```
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a jorbis.jar ./libsrc/jlgui3.0/lib/jorbis.jar
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a jorbis.jar ./lib/zip/jlgui3.0/lib/jorbis.jar
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a jorbis-0.0.15.jar ./lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a jorbis-0.0.15.jar ./libsrc/VorbisSPI1.0.3/lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar
5919b38077fa66784365140cc17f027a jorbis-0.0.15.jar ./lib/zip/VorbisSPI1.0.2/lib/jorbis-0.0.15.jar
```

Please notice the desired output should be sorted by column 1, then by column 2, then by column 3.

How should the command line be modified to produce the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `awk` (which does nothing in your example), I used `sed`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.jar" -print0 \
    | xargs -0 md5sum \
    | sed 's=  \(.*\)/\([^/]\+\)$= \2 \1/\2=' \
    | sort
```

I am not sure whether `sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3` would give you a different result (it didn't for me).

sed regular expression explanation:

```
Match:  \(     .   *   \)        /    \(        [^/]    \+          \)       $
        ^      ^   ^   ^         ^     ^          ^      ^          ^        ^
        |      |   |   |         |     |          |      |          |        |
Start group 1  |   | End group 1 |  Start group 2 |  At least once  |        |
    Match any char |           Slash              |           End group 2    |
              Maybe repeated                  Not a slash                End of line
```

Group1 corresponds to the path, Group2 is the file name.

Replacement is just Group2, space, Group1, slash, Group2 again.

```
\2 \1/\2
```

Comment: Will you edit your answer to include an explanation of the sed command?

Answer (score 1):

Alterntivily with `-exec`

```
sort <<< "$(find . -type f -name "*.jar" -exec bash -c 'echo "$(md5sum $0 | awk "{print \$1}") ${0##*/} $0"' {} \; )"
```

Comment: @axiopisty Updated. Not surprised about speed, `xargs` tends to be slightly faster, especially when dealing with argument lists.